# Scanner in Java doesn't display Windows-1250 characters even though I set it to

Tags: java

I'm trying to use the Java Scanner, but it's not reading Windows-1250 characters, even though I set it up
that it should.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class thing {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in, "Windows-1250");

String thing = scan.nextLine();
System.out.println("output:" + thing);

scan.close();
```

This should result in the Scanner to scan Windows-1250 characters, but it doesn't.

[the terminal shows an empty line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbPgr.png)

Comment: The encoding you pass to `Scanner` **must** be the one that the data on `System.in` arrives it. The code you posted is **only** correct if the data is actually encoded in Windows-1250. If you *don't* specify an encoding then it  will use the platform default encoding which **should** be the correct one. In other words: your code should not need to mention Windows-1250 at all.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I've tried that, still nothing. How do you see/set the platform default encoding? (Using Visual Studio Code, if that matters at all).

Comment: Since you are using VSCode as an input, why do not you simply remove the charset parameter from the Scanner constructor? You can always specify it again if you want to read, let's say, a Windows-1250 encoded subtitle file.

Comment: @VojtechLetal Since that's how they taught me how Scanner works at my high school.

Comment: Then just remove the "Windows-1250" and everything will start magically working.

Comment: @VojtechLetal As I said in one of my previous replies, I tried that, it didn't work.

Comment: Then change the LC_ALL env variable to, I asume in your case, to LC_ALL=cs_CZ.UTF-8 as described in a simmilar issue here
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/7301

Comment: @VojtechLetal How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

This may not resolve your issue, but should greatly help in diagnosing it. Your problem may be one of the 2 kinds: First, that you receive correct info but it is simply displayed incorrectly. And second that you already receive your data incorrectly. Here how I suggest  you diagnose your issue:
There is an Open Source library that has a utility that may convert any String to Unicode sequences and vice-versa. So for instance if you have the following code

```
result = "Hello World";
result = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.encodeStringToUnicodeSequence(result);
System.out.println(result);
result = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.decodeUnicodeSequenceToString(result);
System.out.println(result);
```

The output would be:

```
\u0048\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f\u0020\u0057\u006f\u0072\u006c\u0064
Hello World
```

So I suggest that you modify your code as follows:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class thing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    
        String thing = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("output:" + thing);
        thing = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.encodeStringToUnicodeSequence(thing);
        System.out.println(thing );
        thing = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.decodeUnicodeSequenceToString(thing );
        System.out.println(thing );    
    scan.close();
    }}
```

See what it prints. It will help you to see if your problem is just a display problem or data corruption problem

The library can be found at [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.github.michaelgantman%20AND%20a:MgntUtils) or at [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) It comes as maven artifact and with sources and javadoc

Here is javadoc for the class [StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.html)

Comment: Hey! Tried the thing and it just ­­­[outputs u0000](https://i.imgur.com/2N7Ou41.png) for any of Windows-1250 characters. So this means it's the second problem you mentioned, right? Any idea how I could fix that?

Comment: Yes, it means that you lost your data. Where do you insert your data? on the command line? If so, then your command line can not recognize the symbols in "Windows-1250". So you need to configure your computer that it works in that encoding - Not a Java problem at all. But it would be better to set up computer encoding in UTF-8, or some other UNICODE. It's just better. Any character sets Windows-* should really not be used

Comment: @Oťan, BTW if you used the library could you please give me some feedback, like how easy it was to use, was it helpful etc. Here is the link to the article about the library: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/open-source-java-library-some-useful-utilities-michael-gantman/?trackingId=4%2FpM99jrR2mRPPrIJ06SVA%3D%3D Feel free to write your feedback in the comments section

Comment: Sorry I didn't respond, the library seems nice, might use it eventually when I learn java itself. Any idea how I would configure it? It only doesn't scan it, if I put for ex. 
System.out.println("ěřščššž");
 the output is ěřščššž, so it only happens with the Scanner.

Comment: Like I said, the problem does not relate to java at all. It is your Computer charset configuration. Charset configuration depends on what Operation System you use. In Windows 10 it is called regional settings. There you can choose system locale, but also there you can specify to use UTF-8 for worldwide language support

Comment: I set the [UTF-8 for worldwide language support on](https://i.imgur.com/dIbDa0x_d.webp?maxwidth=760&fidelity=grand), restarted my PC, but still nothing.. I'm starting to think that VSCode is the problem, normal PowerShell works fine.

Comment: VSCode is an environment in it has its own encoding. So yes, you need to change the charset in VSCode (somewhere in its settings). Again I would recommend to use UTF8

Comment: It's UTF-8 by default, so I have no idea what's going wrong...

Comment: Then, I wouldn't know what to tell you, but either way, your problem is not in Java